# Changing type of template at run time

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make a `Matrix` struct which would work with various data types, including my `Complex` struct:

```
struct Complex {
    double re = 0, im = 0;

    Complex operator*(const Complex& other) const {
        return Complex(re * other.re - im * other.im, im * other.re + re * other.im);
    }
    Complex operator*(const double& other) const {
        return Complex(re * other, im * other);
    }

    Complex() {}
    Complex(double a) : re(a) {}
    Complex(double a, double b) : re(a), im(b) {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Complex z) {
    out << z.re << " " << z.im << "i";
    return out;
}

template <typename T>
Complex operator*(const T& c, const Complex& z) {
    return z * c;
}
```

The obvious way is to make a template like one in the code below:

```
template <typename T>
struct Matrix {
    std::vector<T> m;
    unsigned int rows, cols;

    Matrix<Complex> operator*(const Complex& z) const {
        Matrix<Complex> result(rows, cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
            result.m[i] = m[i] * z;
        }
        return result;
    }

    void operator*=(const Complex& z) {
        (*this) = (*this) * z; // <- ideally we're trying to get this to work
    }
    void operator=(const Matrix<T>& other) {
        rows = other.rows;
        cols = other.cols;
        m.resize(rows * cols);
        m = other.m;
    }

    Matrix(const unsigned int& rows, const unsigned int& cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols) {
        m.resize(rows * cols);
    }
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& other) : rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols) {
        (*this) = other;
    }
};

int main() {
    Complex z(1, 1);
    Matrix<double> A(1, 1);
    A.m[0] = 2.0;
    std::cout << (A * z).m[0] << std::endl; // works as it should because a temporary Matrix<Complex> gets created
    A *= z; // and here we're introducing the problem
    std::cout << A.m[0] << std::endl;
}
```

The problem arises when calling `*=` operator. We're trying to call an unexisting `=` operator overload. My first attempt was to write something like this instead:

```
template <typename T_other>
void operator=(const Matrix<T_other>& other) {
    rows = other.rows;
    cols = other.cols;
    m.resize(rows * cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        m[i] = other.m[i];
    }
}
```

This however leads to other problems:

1. The type of `A` is still `Matrix<double>` and after the multiplication it should be `Matrix<Complex>` to store complex numbers.
2. There is no conversion from `Complex` to `double` as it results in loss of data (the imaginary part).

Also, I would like to avoid creating a template specialization for `Matrix<Complex>`, but if there's no other way I'll accept it.

Comment: As a side comment, you might want to consider [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) as an option for your program.

Comment: You'll need to use complex matrices from the get-go. There's unfortunately no real way around it. It's impossible to just change the type of an already-existing object. It might be possible to make a "DoubleOrComplexMatrix" type that contains a variant and changes it as needed.

Comment: Why are you forcing `Complex` value type as argument for multiplication of template `Matrix`? Problem is invalid design of `Matrix` API. Please specify requirements for `Matrix` more carefully. It would be better define `operator*` for `Matrix<double>` and `Complex` as a global function.

Comment: @MarekR It's a result of deleting irrelevant code. In the original one I have one more overload taking `const double&` as a parameter and returning Matrix<T> (which, now that I think about it, may suffer from a similar problem as the one I included).

Comment: Forget matrices and templates for a moment and ask yourself a simple question. What happens when you do `int x = 42; double y = 3.14; x *= y;`?  Does the type of `x` change? Can you have `int x = 42; std::complex<double> y = {3, 14}; x *= y;`? If not, why not?

Comment: Regarding the `*=` function: your API should simply support that operation only for scalar type `T`. Moreover, as people already said, use `std::complex` and an appropriate matrix library, e.g. Eigen.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I know. I would somehow need to change the type of `x` after doing `x *= y`, which is apparently impossible. I think I'll just stick with complex matrices as @Jonathan S. suggested.

Comment: Also, to people recommending me stuff like `std::complex` - the whole point of this hobby project is to make my own ones, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**C++ is statically typed.**  Once you declare a variable and type, you can't change the type of that variable.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Matrix {
    void operator*=(const Complex& z) {
        (*this) = (*this) * z;
    }
}
```

The `*=` operator overload for your `Matrix` doesn't make sense.  A `Complex` can hold the value of a `double` with imaginary part 0, but a `double` can never hold the value of a `Complex`.

Multiplying a real matrix by a complex number necessarily produces a complex matrix.  So you try and assign the complex RHS to the real LHS - and either that makes no sense and shouldn't be done, or you have some idea for how to convert that (e.g. keep real part, keep absolute value etc) and then have to implement a `Matrix<double>` constructor from `Matrix<Complex>`.

Real numbers are a subset of complex numbers, so just make `A` a `Matrix<Complex>` from the beginning if you ever want to make it complex later.